# C# Excel - AutoFilter stopping at first blank cell

Tags: c#, excel

Good Afternoon,

I'm having some issues with running a filter on a spreadsheet to delete blank cells.

I'm using the below code which should filter the whole range of the spreadsheet but it stops at the first empty row and then the autofilter fails.

```
Range spreadsheetLast = spreadSheetWs.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
Range spreadsheetRange = spreadSheetWs.get_Range("A1", "T" + spreadsheetLast.Row);
spreadsheetRange.AutoFilter(1, "=", XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, Type.Missing, true);
Range xlFilteredRange = spreadsheetRange.Offset[1, 0].SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);
```

I'm then deleting the rows using

```
xlFilteredRange.EntireRow.Delete(XlDirection.xlUp);
```

This is deleting basically everything off the spreadsheet. I've tried playing around with the offset and had no luck.

I attempted to change the range to be manual while testing to "A1", "T9999" and this didnt work either.

Any help much appreciated,

Mark

Edit: Changed code back to original

Comment: Isn't that how Excel works? It would be strange if the behavior changed because you invoke it through code instead of the UI

Comment: It is the normal behavior for excel when you select the first row but not the whole range, usually selecting the whole range in excel will still filter past blank rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the `AutoFilter` and use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete` to find blank cells in a `Range` and delete them.

In VBA (and maybe C#?) you can just use the whole column (`A:A`) as the `Range` for this.

The following VBA works fine for me to delete all the rows which have a blank in the first column.  I assume this will translate to C# easily and work via interop also.

```
Sub DeleteBlanksFromColumnA()

    Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```